# ubuntu 12.10 openldap issue Invalid DN syntax (34)"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openldap, ubuntu-12.10

I'm following: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/openldap-server.html and when I get to the part that says

> ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b dc=example,dc=com dn

I get:

```
Invalid DN syntax (34)
Additional information: invalid DN
```

I noticed:

```
sudo ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config dn
dn: cn=config
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You have no schema defined. In order to perform your example search you need a schema with something close to the following definitions which are taken from `core.schema`.

```
olcAttributeTypes: ( 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25 NAME ( 'dc' 'domainComponent' ) DESC 'RFC1274/2247: domain component' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SUBSTR caseIgnoreIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )  
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.344 NAME 'dcObject' DESC 'RFC2247: domain component object' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST dc )
```

In fact, you should probably just add `core.schema` to your `slapd`, ubuntu-12.10 uses `slapd-config` so, you'll actually be adding a `.ldif` file.

`sudo ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/core.ldif`

Depending on what you're doing you'll probably also want:

- `cosine` (required for inetorgperson)
- `inetorgperson`
- `nis` (I recommend `rfc2307bis`, but you'd have to take it from elsewhere.)
- `misc` (mail routing)